# Bootstrap3 nav-bar fixed to the top of the page is blocking the top content of the page below the bar, how do I fix this?

Tags: java, spring-boot, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

In the image below you will see that my navbar is at the top of the page however it is slightly covering the heading that is supposed to be beneath it. How do I fix this?

[image]

My code for the navigation bar:

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
 <div class="container-fluid">
   <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
<div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data- 
 toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="userProfile1">
     <img alt="Brand"">
  </a>
</div>

<!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

    <li><a href="userProfile1">Profile</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Menu <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="/logout">Logout</a></li>

  </ul>
</div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
```

I added the following to my CSS file but it didn't change anything:

```
 body {
   padding-top: 60px;
}
 @media (max-width: 979px) {
   body {
     padding-top: 0px;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always give your heading a DIV tag and give that div a margin-top.

CSS:

```
.heading-text {
    margin-top: 100px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="heading-text">
    <h1>My Title</h1>
</div>
```